# Average of SQL divide

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the average of a ratio in SQL.

My table looks like this:

```
T_TOTAL  |  NUM_ASSETS
----------------------
   32    |     8
   20    |     4
   24    |     4
```

And so that value I'm after is **5** as in:

```
T_TOTAL  |  NUM_ASSETS  |  T_TOTAL/NUM_ASSETS
---------------------------------------------
   32    |     8        |         4
   20    |     4        |         5
   24    |     4        |         6
                          -------------------
                             AVG = 5
```

So far I have this but it's not working:

```
SELECT T_TOTAL As Time, NUM_ASSETS As Assets,
Time/Assets As TimePerAsset, AVG(TimePerAsset) As Result
FROM MATCHES
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @dan04 I'm getting 'invalid column name' errors on the aliases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select avg(t_total/num_assets) from matches
```

And if you have 0 in num_assets, you can avoid a division by 0 like this:

```
select avg(t_total/nullif(num_assets, 0)) from matches
```

Comment: that will throw an error because a division by zero is illegal

Comment: Worked perfectly including avoiding division by 0. Mange tak.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name which is why i posted a second sql to handle that

Comment: I mis-understood what nullif does. I thought it would return 0 if num_assets was null. (I'm not a SQL Server user)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  t.*,
        Result = AVG(TimePerAsset)
  FROM  (
            SELECT  [Time] = T_TOTAL, 
                    [Assets] = NUM_ASSETS,
                    [TimePerAsset] = CASE WHEN NUM_ASSETS <> 0 
                                          THEN T_TOTAL/NUM_ASSETS
                                          ELSE NULL
                                   END
              FROM MATCHES
        ) t
```

Comment: tried your solution but it gave me an error "invalid column name 'Time'"

Comment: @greener, thats because `Time` is a keyword in MSSQL :). answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT M.Time, M.Assets, M.TimePerAsset, Avg(M.TimePerAsset) as AvgTimePerAsset
FROM 
(
    SELECT T_TOTAL As TotalTime
        , NUM_ASSETS As Assets
        , CASE WHEN NUM_ASSETS <> 0 THEN T_TOTAL/NUM_ASSETS ELSE NULL END As TimePerAsset
    FROM Matches
) M
GROUP BY M.Time, M.Assets, M.TimePerAsset
```

Comment: I see what you mean about dividing by 0. it's giving an error though "invalid column name 'Assets'". But it's just an alias?

Comment: you are correct, I updated my answer to not use the alias in that location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT T_TOTAL As Time, NUM_ASSETS As Assets,
case when Assets <> 0 then Time/Assets end As TimePerAsset, AVG(case when Assets <> 0 then Time/Assets end) As Result
FROM MATCHES
```

Comment: tried your solution but it gave me an error "invalid column name 'Time'"